# Why gameObject get such positions in Unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, position

I want to create 2d game.
Structure of objects

[image]
    []

"View" present a square where everything happens.

"Initial" This is the same square with a mask

"SquareList" is empty panel.

Why am I doing this?

I created a script where when I click on the screen, a new square is added to the SquareList. SquareList is the parent. I created a script to determine the position of the cursor.

```
createPos = new Vector2 (Input.mousePosition.x, Input.mousePosition.y);
```

Next, I want to set for new object position = cursor position.

Cursor.position equivalent = (562,1134 / 242.6486)
But the new object get position (94931.29 / 103365.6 / -17280)

But if I set position of new object to = new Vector(0,0);
Then everything is fine

What is the problem?

Comment: ohh, I understood what the point was, it was necessary to use  Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Input.mousePosition` returns position in pixel-coordinate. You have to use `Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint` to convert it to world position then assign that to the object. If 3D Object, add an offset to it before converting with `ScreenToWorldPoint`.

```
public GameObject prefab;
public float offset = 10f;

void Update()
{
    if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
    {
        Vector3 clickPos;

        clickPos = Input.mousePosition;
        clickPos.z = offset;

        clickPos = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(clickPos);
        GameObject obj = Instantiate(prefab, clickPos, Quaternion.identity);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hello nameless brother/sister! I believe you are seeing this issue because your game object's coordinates are affected by its parent's coordinates. You may need to use **localPosition** to find more relative coordinates.

More info: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform-localPosition.html